# Asammdf GUI not recognizing ID column as IDs (for CAN/J1939 IDs)

Tags: python, can-bus, mdf, asammdf, j1939

I'm trying to load [this MF4 (MDF) file](https://github.com/Tyronnosaurus/J1939-Decoder/blob/55764cc6a42e967d34f9236c20c97cc5c8745988/Results/ExampleLog.mf4) into asammdf GUI to extract its signals. The MF4 was created with Python using J1939 data extracted from a vehicle.
The MF4 loads correctly into asammdf GUI, and in the Bus Logging tab I've loaded a DBC dictionary. When I use 'Extract Bus Signals', I get the message:

> CAN bus summary:
>
> - 0 **of** **0 IDs** in the MDF4 file were matched in the DBC and converted
> - no unknown IDs inf the MDF4 file

It appears asammdf does not recognize the ID column, probably because it is incorrectly formatted. What requirements are missing in this MF4 file for the ID column to be correctly interpreted as IDs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the problem seems to be with the DBC file. Does it contain messages?

Comment: It contains J1939 messages (ID, payload...). I used [your code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681944/17029705) along with data obtained with a CAN sniffer and parsed from a proprietary format. [My code here](https://github.com/Tyronnosaurus/J1939-Decoder).

Comment: Sorry, read MDF instead of DBC. The DBC dictionary is [this one](https://github.com/nberlette/canbus/blob/main/dbc/j1939.dbc) and also the sample dowloadable [here](https://canlogger.csselectronics.com/canedge-getting-started/log-file-tools/).