# How to make extract_bus_logging in asammdf decode raw can data of length longer than 8?

Tags: python, can-bus, asammdf, j1939

I have an MF4 file with raw can data and want to decode this to get the physical values. It seems like the decoding of all signals with length 8 (as defined in the dbc file) is working as expected. However, I have a segment in the dbc file that looks like this

```
BO_ 2381841918 GNSS_PositionData: 51 GNSS 
 SG_ GNSS_Longitude : 120|64@1- (1E-016,0) [-180|180] "deg"  Tester 
 SG_ GNSS_Latitude : 56|64@1- (1E-016,0) [-90|90] "deg"  Tester
```

that is not being decoded (I cannot find any signals defined in this section after decoding) when trying in asammdf. However, when I decode the data with the same dbc in canoe it works and I can see all data. Also, what I can see in canoe is that the event types for signals of length 8 and length 51 are "CAN frame" and "j1939 frame" respectively. Or more accurately, the signals of longer length have both event types, see image below.
[canoe_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFOY3.png)

Is there any setting in asammdf I'm missing or is it not possible to decode?

**Note**: As you probably understand I'm no expert on CAN data so if I'm missing something fundamental please inform me!

This is what I've tried in asammdf according to the documentation.

```
from asammdf import MDF

with MDF(path_to_mdf_file) as mdf:
    db = {"CAN": [("GNSS.dbc", 7)]}
    extracted_mdf = mdf.extract_bus_logging(database_files=db)
```

I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630991/create-mf4-to-be-decode-by-j1939-dbc-asammdf) question on stackoverflow and I've been looking through the sources (both source_type and bus_type) of all signals in the raw MF4 and cannot really see anything that differs in between groups.

Comment: CAN or CAN FD? CAN cannot have more than 8 bytes data per frame and I don't think J1939 supports CAN FD.

Comment: Haven't heard of CAN FD but it definitely sounds like it when reading [here](https://www.kvaser.com/about-can/can-fd/). Do you have any idea on how to go about decoding CAN FD using the asammdf library? Not possible?

Comment: This seems to be what is used: [fast packet protocol](https://copperhilltech.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-sae-j1939-and-nmea-2000/). _"The Fast Packet protocol defined in NMEA 2000 provides a means to stream up to 223 bytes of data, with the advantage that each frame retains the parameter group identity and priority"_ Any experience on this? @Lundin

Comment: Both of those are application-level protocols using classic 8 byte CAN as data-link layer. Application-level protocols often have some means of sending larger chunks of data across multiple CAN frames.